# How do I generate the Bitcoin Cash hash preimage?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, hash, signature, bip143

I am attempting to manually generate a signed transaction which is to be sent from my address `1GiJZtN7wjUuL4V5i7ZYYDAvFtqi5AhCDr` which is `bitcoincash:qzk9nxh6qpd9yt3hvv6vvun78s834f3escdhu2vdjp` in the new address format. I am using an uncompressed public key in this transaction.

I have the following unsigned Bitcoin Cash transaction. How do I find its hash preimage which is the hash used in the signing of this transaction?

> 0100000001fb4a8e5c7ac5311f32fbe127f031134ee3e7490f3308ca19c567f78d6aa96d770000000000ffffffff0100a00700000000001976a914a8e181e0847b495df439066ca8fb36ce093692be88ac00000000

Breaking it up, it looks like this:

`01000000` - nVersion

`01` - num of inputs

`fb4a8e5c7ac5311f32fbe127f031134ee3e7490f3308ca19c567f78d6aa96d77` - txid (little-endian)

`00000000` - vout

`00` - size of sigScript

`ffffffff` - sequence number

`01` - num of outputs

`00a0070000000000` - amount (hex, little-endian)

`1976a914a8e181e0847b495df439066ca8fb36ce093692be88ac` - scriptPubKey

`00000000` - timeLock

I am attempting to consume output 0 from the transaction with txid: `776da96a8df767c519ca08330f49e7e34e1331f027e1fb321f31c57a5c8e4afb`,
The scriptPubKey for that transaction's output 0 is:

```
1976a914ac599afa005a522e376334c6727e3c0f1aa6398688ac
```

The value of the received output is 0.005 BCH

The transaction I am attempting to consume can be found here:
[https://bch.btc.com/776da96a8df767c519ca08330f49e7e34e1331f027e1fb321f31c57a5c8e4afb](https://bch.btc.com/776da96a8df767c519ca08330f49e7e34e1331f027e1fb321f31c57a5c8e4afb.rawhex)
And the rawtx for the transaction I want to consume is here:
[https://bch.btc.com/776da96a8df767c519ca08330f49e7e34e1331f027e1fb321f31c57a5c8e4afb.rawhex](https://bch.btc.com/776da96a8df767c519ca08330f49e7e34e1331f027e1fb321f31c57a5c8e4afb)

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin Cash uses [BIP 143](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0143.mediawiki) for signature hash creation.

From the BIP:

> ```
>   Double SHA256 of the serialization of:
>      1. nVersion of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
>      2. hashPrevouts (32-byte hash)
>      3. hashSequence (32-byte hash)
>      4. outpoint (32-byte hash + 4-byte little endian) 
>      5. scriptCode of the input (serialized as scripts inside CTxOuts)
>      6. value of the output spent by this input (8-byte little endian)
>      7. nSequence of the input (4-byte little endian)
>      8. hashOutputs (32-byte hash)
>      9. nLocktime of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
>     10. sighash type of the signature (4-byte little endian)
> ```

So the hash preimage will look like this:

```
01000000be16f25831b40c713fed6627e39aa7717170f5cdd62c765bd4882abbefdaa50e3bb13029ce7b1f559ef5e747fcac439f1455a2ec7c5f09b72290795e70665044fb4a8e5c7ac5311f32fbe127f031134ee3e7490f3308ca19c567f78d6aa96d77000000001976a914ac599afa005a522e376334c6727e3c0f1aa6398688ac20a1070000000000ffffffffc8e2e71fe663fc91d7aa109feffee0f1497862af35525f68f500cbd55f6ed6620000000041000000
```

And here is its breakdown:

```
nVersion: 01000000
hashPrevouts: be16f25831b40c713fed6627e39aa7717170f5cdd62c765bd4882abbefdaa50e
hashSequence: 3bb13029ce7b1f559ef5e747fcac439f1455a2ec7c5f09b72290795e70665044
outpoint: fb4a8e5c7ac5311f32fbe127f031134ee3e7490f3308ca19c567f78d6aa96d7700000000
scriptCode: 1976a914ac599afa005a522e376334c6727e3c0f1aa6398688ac
value: 20a1070000000000
nSequence: ffffffff
hashOutputs: c8e2e71fe663fc91d7aa109feffee0f1497862af35525f68f500cbd55f6ed662
nLocktime: 00000000
sighash: 41000000
```

Comment: I get the "hashPrevouts" to be:
"be16f25831b40c713fed6627e39aa7717170f5cdd62c765bd4882abbefdaa50e" which is sha256d("fb4a8e5c7ac5311f32fbe127f031134ee3e7490f3308ca19c567f78d6aa96d7700000000").



Who of us is right?

Comment: Hmm, yes, you're right. I will edit the answer

Comment: What exactly does this value of the sighash field mean?

Comment: Sighash indicates what data exactly is being signed. It's a type indicator.